# jQuery .serialize not posting to PHP.. or is it the PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, serialization, post

Related to my question yesterday: My two radio buttons that will change prices on change:

```
<form id="f-p" method="post" action="forms.php">
         <label for="exkl">Exkl. moms</label>
         <input name="moms" id="exkl" type="radio" value="exkl" checked="checked" onClick="javascript:thisWorks();"/>
         <label for="inkl">Inkl. moms</label>
         <input name="moms" id="inkl" type="radio" value="" onClick="javascript:thisWorks();"/>
  </form>
```

I intend to use this PHP:

```
if ($_POST["moms"] = "exkl") {
   echo "Nothing.";
 } else if($_POST["moms"] = "inkl") {
$inkl_query ="SELECT `product_id` FROM `cms_module_products_fieldvals` WHERE `fielddef_id`=4";
$iresult = mysql_query($inkl_query);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($iresult)) {
   var_dump($row);
   $inkVal = $row->value;
   echo $InkVal;
 }
}
```

with this jQuery to post the value:

```
function thisWorks() {
$.ajax({
    data: $('form#f-p').serialize() + "&formSubmit=true",
    type: "POST",
    url:"forms.php", 
    success: function() {
            tar = $('form#f-p').serialize();
            alert(tar);
        }
    });
}
$('input[name=moms]').change(thisWorks);
thisWorks();
```

Now, I am getting the alerts from the Jquery with the posted values, so they are working there. It will either say "moms=inkl" or "moms=exkl". (Don't know whether that is the problem. But they are not working in the PHP. I do not get the mySQL Query. The page loads and any value change doesn't produce any change in how PHP handles the form. What's going on?

Comment: it's always fun to start with a phpinfo(); on a page that is intended to parse the results to see how the data is being transferred / received by PHP

Comment: yeah. there were no post variables there.

Comment: you should show the text produced by the php script in the ajax success function via alert, or you could use firebug to see the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a problem:

```
if ($_POST["moms"] = "exkl") {
   echo "Nothing.";
 } else if($_POST["moms"] = "inkl") {
```

Your `if` statement is always `true`, because `$_POST["moms"] = "exkl"` isn't checking equality. It' just sets `$_POST["moms"]` equal to `"exkl"`. Same goes for the `else if`.

Change this code:

```
if ($_POST["moms"] = "exkl") {
   echo "Nothing.";
 } else if($_POST["moms"] = "inkl") {
```

To this code:

```
if ($_POST["moms"] == "exkl") {
   echo "Nothing.";
 } else if($_POST["moms"] == "inkl") {
```

And see what happens.

Comment: No joy. It looks like the PHP isn't getting the data at all, so maybe it never gets to this step.

Comment: For this form, yes. I just wanted to do something simple to see if it would work. This is all that I have in forms.php.

Comment: Does your PHP script even run?

Comment: Now I don't think so. So it's back to the drawing board for that.

Comment: Like you said before, the PHP was just setting my post to inkl or exkl. So whichever one was first happened. I'd either get "Nothing" or the database info, but no change after that.

Comment: PHP wasn't catching the jQuery post. Don't know why. But I went at this a different way and solved it. Thanks anyway.